# formula needed to find and highlight a cell in a column that has the same first 7 characters as another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

formula needed to find and highlight a cell in a column that has the same first 7 characters as another column

I have a document where I am scanning barcodes into (column V) where I need to find and highlight the cell or cells in column L that has the exact same first 7 characters.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please show a data sample. How many cells are in column V? how many in column L? Mock up the result. Show what you have tried. Explain what about your approach is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula works when used as the formula controlling a Conditional Formatting rule:

```
=LEFT(L1,7)=LEFT($V$1,7)
```

`LEFT(L1,7)` gets the first seven characters of cell L1 for the test ON L1. `LEFT($V$1,7)` does the same for cell V1, a single cell in which I shall suppose you are scanning a barcode and looking over for highlights, taking whatever actions, and scanning again. `There is a limitation here that I shall get to shortly.`

For the second half of the comparison, V1 is referenced absolutely so each line is compared to IT, not to the column V cell in its own row.

The limitation is that it will only work when scanning into the single input cell. Of course, it seems pretty unlikely you want to scan in 1,000 barcodes, then see everything that matched for any one or a hundred of the scanned in codes. So just the one input cell, as is.

However, if you don't mind an expanded Conditional Formatting condition, just add as many more rules as you need for all the input cells you want, using each one's own address instead of $V$1. Why use extra rules instead of a longer formula? Because a longer formula would be like the above example of a mess of highlighted cells in column L that match... some... input, but... which input? Separate rules for each input cell would allow you to use different colors for each rule, or some mix of several formats, whatever stands out for YOU. So you'd see several (say you did four rules, or a dozen) color highlights in column L and that might help your work. Just be sure to check none of the rules have the `Stop if True` checkbox at the right checked so the Conditional Format works its way through all the rules instead of stopping!

If the cells in column L that fail to match are unimportant, even distracting, you might also consider adding a rule that tests for `<>` instead of `equals` and color their text white to match the background making non-matches "disappear" from the screen.